Assumption of molecular chaos (confusion)
The molecular chaos means that the velocities of the two particles are uncorrelated before the collision. However, this is no longer the case after the collision, which is why the whole problem with the time reversal arises.
According to my professor, this is the heart of the kinetic theory of gases. As far as I understand, this approach is what gives rise to the important H-theorem in the first place.
Personally, I somehow have the problem of understanding this approach correctly and this annoys me because, as mentioned above, it is very important. I don't understand the term in this context and I also don't understand why the velocities before the collision should be correlated at all.... The question came to me: Does correlated in this context mean that I can deduce the speed of one particle from the speed of the other?
I would be very happy if someone could explain the approach a little more clearly.
Thank you in advance!

I highly recommend looking into Dorfman's An Introduction to Chaos in Nonequilibrium Statistical Mechanics especially the second chapter "Boltzmann's equation" where this classic argument is treated in detail in a toy model to build intuition (Kac ring)

Ah thanks, i will take a look at this chapter! I also think we had the Kac ring as a part of an exercise sheet, i guess im going through that again!
